# How to lookup multiple items in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has `uid` has its primary key. Given an array of `uid` values, I need to be able to query all the items in the table whose `uid` matches any of the supplied `uid` values.

This is what I tried (an example with 3 uids to look up):

```
{
  "TableName": "my_table",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "uid IN (:entry_0,:entry_1,:entry_2)",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":entry_0": {
      "S": "4e77576f-f92c-449d-8729-070b7568b349"
    },
    ":entry_1": {
      "S": "7f9edaf4-be64-49d4-a6b5-f18f7dce7c79"
    },
    ":entry_2": {
      "S": "eca6134e-aad5-473c-83c3-9b4fda554588"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error:

```
Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN
```

Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: Using your solution, I now get a new error:
Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use a batchGet query here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

You can send multiple ids and any no of ids will still return in about 20-30ms for primary key queries.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.